# Sitecore: target item has no version in this language error

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, content-editor

I have an issue with new sub-page creation using the languge which doesn't exist for the parent item.

I have an item with german language version only.
I switched to english language for this item and tried to add a sub-item. 
I have got the error message "target item has no version in this language error".
This happened under Content Editor user account. 
It works perfectly when I using Administrator account.
Please help me to find the reason.
Thank you in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was our bug. Question is closed.